# With regard to random variables, does $(X/Y)$ independent of $(Y)$ imply that $(X)$ is independent of $(Y)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, independence

This makes logical sense to me, but I can't seem to prove this. Is this statement true?

Note: X/Y is a ratio here, not conditioning.

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: If $X=Y$ then $X/Y=1$ is independent of $Y$, but $X$ is definitely not independent of $Y$.

Comment: X and Y are random variables.

Comment: It _ought to be_ clear that this statement is **false** for $X/Y$ may cancel the dependence of $X$ with $Y$ and shown in the comment above.

Comment: By $X/Y$ you mean a division or a condition ?

Comment: Division. The ratio of X and Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, that is false. Just make $X=aY$ (extremely dependent variables) and then $X/Y=a$ is independent of $Y$.

It's also false in the other direction. Suppose $X,Y$ are independent, then, letting $Z=X/Y$ (and assuming $Y\ne 0$) then $$P(Z=z | Y=y)= P(X = yz)$$

This will only be independent of $y$ if $X$ is uniform.